# Break On first Line When Attaching Debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Say I have a project with many entry points and also have scripts which load the various entry points depending on the situation.

I know I can set the `-Xrunjdwp` option with `suspend=y` in order to pause the program until a debugger is attached. In my startup script for debugging I provide this option whenever I launch any java class. The problem is that there are times during debugging where I'm not sure what entry point is going to be called.

So my question is; is it possible with Intellij (or some plugin or some other method) to automatically break on the first line of code after you attach the debugger? Almost like doing a *'step-into'* for the JVM invoking any class's `main` method.